# Rally Plugin for IntelliJ - Proxy issue

Tags: proxy, intellij-idea

The Rally Plug-in for IntelliJ has an issue to connect with Rally using Proxy settings. 
It doesn't seem that the rally plugin uses the proxy settings from IntelliJ.
Has anybody encountered this issue and have found a fix?
On the settings, I am able to successfully 'Check Connection' from the 'Http Proxy' node to Rally site. 
However, from Rally node, when i click 'Test Connection', it says 'Unknown Host: rally1.rallydev.com'
Any workaround/solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Rally Plugin does not support going through a Proxy ( See [**this**](https://github.com/RallySoftware/intellij-plugin/issues/14)).

However, a workaround might be possible using [**Proxifier**](http://www.proxifier.com/) which I have used in the past to force applications to go through a proxy.

This was useful specially for legacy apps that did not support a proxy. Once setup, you should be able to see the rally1 connections being attempted and being 'proxified'.